# wget error : Failed writing HTTP request ,no such file or directory

Tags: http, wget

I am using this command to send a http request to google :

wget  --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0" --post-data=test.wav --header="Content-Type: audio/L16; rate=44100"        "http://www.google.com/speech-api/v1/recognize?xjerr=1&client=chromium&lang=zh-CN&maxresult=1"

but wget keep failing and retrying.

[image]

Comment: does test.wav actually exist?

Comment: yes. BTW, its size is 195kb